# SAP Fiori Default Values App: "no editor metadata" / "no configured plugin"

Tags: sap-fiori

My customer set up a new S/4HANA system and installed some Fiori apps. When I go into my user settings in the Fiori LaunchPad and navigate into the Default Values tab, I:

1. don't get a value help,
2. entered values, e.g. Controlling Area, are not propagated into the backend's user parameter's (SU01).

Per Chrome Developer Tools I get the following error messages. I suspect that something is misconfigured causing the above 2 observations?

[image]

The following parameter names have no editor metadata and thus likely no configured plugin:
"AssetDepreciationArea",
"CompanyCode",
"ControllingArea",
"CostCenter",
"ExchangeRateType",
"FinancialStatementVariant",
"FiscalYear",
"FunctionalArea",
"GLAccount",
"GLAccountHierarchy",
"InternalOrder",
"Ledger",
"LedgerFiscalYear",
"Material",
"MaterialGroup",
"MaterialType",
"Plant",
"ProfitCenter",
"Segment",
"StatisticalKeyFigure",
"StorageLocation".

Comment: Does it correspond to the symptom described in [SAP KBA 2619218 - Cannot Display Available Default Values in Fiori Launchpad](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002619218)?

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi, no. It doesn't provide a value help at all. As in, the icon for the value help is missing entirely.

I have also checked the following notes: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2519765
https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/3079798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. The issue was a misconfiguration. The customer has added the correct navigation targets in the respective catalogues. This solves problems (1) and (2).